# Model generic Typescript type to enforce multiple props have same set of keys

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, data-structures, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create this generic `<FormBuilder />` component. I wan't it to take two different set of props, `defaultValues` and `fields`. Using generics, I wan't to enforce that both props are using the exact same keys.

Here is what I have came up with so far (which also might help explain what I'm trying to achieve):

A `<FormBuilder />` component that can generate forms, with an API like this.

```
<FormBuilder
  initialValues={{
    firstName: undefined,
    lastName: undefined,
  }}
  fields={{
    firstName: { type: 'text', label: 'First Name', required: true },
    lastName: { type: 'text', label: 'Last Name', required: true },
  }}
  onSubmit={value => {
    // Value is strongly typed, with keys 'firstName' and 'lastName'
  }}
/>
```

This is nice, and gives me strong type checking. If I remove or add one thing from one of the props, Typescript will give me a warning. This will ensure me that I never forget to update the other prop when doing some changes. Also the `onSubmit()` callback will also have strong types containing the exact keys used.

[image: Screenshot of usage]

From the "outside" this component works great.  **The problem is the fact that this is using the `Record<>` type, which I can't iterate over while still keeping my strong types.**

Below you can see my implementation of this component. As you can see I had to create my own `iterator()` function to iterate over the data in a nicer way, and I also have to typecast some of the values.

```
type FormProps<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  fields: Record<K, FieldItem>;
  initialValues: Record<K, string | undefined>;
  onSubmit: (value: Record<K, string | undefined>) => void;
};

export function FormBuilder<T, K extends keyof T>(props: FormProps<T, K>) {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState<Record<K, string | undefined>>(props.initialValues);
  
  function handleSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.onSubmit(fields);
  }
  
  function handleChange(value: FieldOutput) {
    setFields({ ...fields, [value.name]: value.value });
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {iterator(fields).map(({ value, key }) => (
        <React.Fragment key={key as string}>
          <FieldFactory valueKey={key as string} value={value} field={props.fields[key]} onChange={handleChange} />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </form>
  );
}
```

The same issues arises on the "outside" of this component, when I need to iterate over the values in the `onSubmit()` handler.

The iterator is implemented as follows.

```
export function iterator<Item>(item: Item) {
  const result: Array<{ key: keyof typeof item; value: Item[keyof typeof item] }> = [];

  let k: keyof Item;
  for (k in item) {
    const value = item[k];
    result.push({ value, key: k });
  }
  return result;
}
```

#### What I'm looking for

I'm open to various suggestions. Either a way to iterate over the object while still keeping the types (this seems difficult/impossible from what I can see from other SO posts), or maybe and alternative way to type/structure the data, and still achieve the same effect.

I have tried using `Array` and `Set` without any luck there.

Comment: Please share reproducible example in any code sandbox which support typescript

Comment: Why not store the default in the field btw?

Comment: Does this question depend on react?  If so, you might want to tag it as such.  If not, you should probably provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mpD36m) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @H.B. I want to seperate the configuration of the fields from the actual data. For some seperation of concerns. Also, if I combine them, the issue would be the same with the combined prop, and the onSubmit callback.